# Scipy Simpsons Function - Output not matching expectations

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, integral, simpsons-rule

I am attempting to use the scipy Simpson function to integrate timeseries data, but I am having doubts about the value it returns as it doesn't match up with what I am expecting to get. Here is my [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cr1UYsWERr3UHQXLs-Tfyq7lSsV2jOfm/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112361413704533623091&rtpof=true&sd=true). It's just one column of timestamps and one column of floats.

Here's my code:

```
# p is the filepath
df = pd.read_excel(p)
df.columns = ['t','P']
df['t'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df['t']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
x = simpson(df['P'],df['t'])
y = df['P'].mean() * (df['t'].max()-df['t'].min()) / 3600
```

When I take a simple average of my data and multiply by the duration (~2 hrs), I get around 1000, which is what I am expecting to get. However, the Simpson function keeps returns around 655, well below what my expectations. The data forms a simple rectangle when graphed so not sure what is causing this issue.

[Graphed Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Xbg.png)

Any idea where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There are some repeating time values... I'm not sure if Simpson's Rule is useful in this situation...